# Using catch_the_image to get the thumbnail size

Tags: post-thumbnails, cropping, scale

I use front end posting on my site so I don't get a chance to set a featured image for alot of my posts. So I use catch_the_image to get thumbs but it gets the original size and then scales it which is hurting page speed. Basically what I want to do is add "-150x150" into the string in the function so it pulls the smallest size of the 3 it stores in the uploads folder. So instead of picture.png it returns picture-150x150.png. Any idea how to add that to this function?

```
function catch_that_image() {
 global $post, $posts;
 $first_img = '';
 ob_start();
 ob_end_clean();
 $output = preg_match_all('/<img.+src=[\'"]([^\'"]+)[\'"].*>/i', $post->post_content, $matches);
 $first_img = $matches [1] [0];

 return $first_img;
}
```

Comment: Actually you can set the featured image on front end posting, using set_post_thumbnail [codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/set_post_thumbnail)

Comment: How do I use that in my situation? People post from front end and can add an image and then I use the first image they post as the thumb.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add your own named image size by adding code to your functions.php.

Something in the line of
    add_theme_support('post-thumbnails');//might not be necessary
    add_image_size('front-end-150', 300, 300);

Now you should be able to use in your catch_that_image()

```
wp_get_attachment_image($post->ID, 'front-end-150')
```

for all newly uploaded images.

Your past images don't have the front-end-150, so you might want to use the regenerate thumbnail plugin (http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/regenerate-thumbnails/)

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

An alternative is to put the upload form `<input type="file">` in the front end posting form & process it along / after the rest of the function.

Here is the file input:

```
<input type="file" id="profile-picture" name="profile-picture[]" size="40" multiple />
```

Just change the name attribute accordingly. The `[]` on the attribute value & the `multiple` is for multiple file upload.

The attaching function :

```
function attach_uploads($uploads,$post_id = 0){
$files = rearrange($uploads);
if($files[0]['name']==''){
    return false;   
}
foreach($files as $file){
    $upload_file = wp_handle_upload( $file, array('test_form' => false) );
    $attachment = array(
    'post_mime_type' => $upload_file['type'],
    'post_title' => preg_replace('/\.[^.]+$/', '', basename($upload_file['file'])),
    'post_content' => '',
    'post_status' => 'inherit'
);
    $attach_id = wp_insert_attachment( $attachment, $upload_file['file'], $post_id );
    $attach_array[] = $attach_id;
    require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/image.php');
    $attach_data = wp_generate_attachment_metadata( $attach_id, $upload_file['file'] );
    wp_update_attachment_metadata( $attach_id, $attach_data );
}
return $attach_array;
}
```

You can find more on the rearrange function [here](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.multiple.php).

And the additional function to attach as post_thumbnail

```
// put this along the other $_POST
$files = $_FILES['profile-picture'];

// insert attachment, after you have created the new post id → $post_id
$attached_files = attach_uploads($files,$post_id);

// set the first file as post thumbnail
if($attached_files){
    set_post_thumbnail( $post_id, $attached_files[0] ); 
}
```

Hope this help